# How do I run Zandronum on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, games

I have downloaded the linux executable for Zandronum, but I can't get it to run. I have searched all over google for a solution and tried everything, but I still get this:

```
/home/censored/Downloads/Doom/zandronum/zandronum: 
error while loading shared libraries: 
libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
```

Comment: -do you have a libssl on your system? -if another version symlinking might be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open a terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8*
```

Then, try running the server again. Also, FYI there is a ppa. You can install it by executing the following commands in an open terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://debian.drdteam.org/ stable multiverse'
wget -O - http://debian.drdteam.org/drdteam.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

And to install packages:

```
sudo apt-get install zandronum doomseeker-zandronum
```

More applications are available from that ppa as well.

If you don't want to install the ppa, you can download the .deb packages from here [debian.drdteam.org](http://debian.drdteam.org/pool/multiverse/). Just keep an eye on which version[s] you download (amd64 or i386). To install dependencies along with installation of a downloaded deb you can either open the file using software-center or you can install gdebi and use that instead. Otherwise, just use `dpkg -i filename.deb` and run `sudo apt-get -f install` after to fix dependencies.